# overide ForeignKey field

Tags: django, django-models

Using the django docs example below if i have a similar model setup it will look like this.but looking at the Album app it can be used for my other thing the problem for me will be the ForeignKey if i created a new app Photographer and what to add an Album how will i achieve this that albums mean different things for different people or context

```
class Musician(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    instrument = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Musician)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    release_date = models.DateField()
    num_stars = models.IntegerField()

class Photographer(models.Model):
    # some stuff here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using simple model inheritance as follows:

```
class Musician(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    instrument = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Photographer(models.Model):
    # some stuff here    

class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    release_date = models.DateField()
    num_stars = models.IntegerField()

class PhotoAlbum(Album):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Photographer)

class MusicAlbum(Album):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Musician)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to relate an object to any other object is to use a generic relationship.

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations for an example of how to accomplish this.

Generics are nice because you can avoid concrete inheritance, unless you need it.